# Cheat Engine for Mac OS X or Linux

Tags: linux, macos, memory, editing, disassembly

> Cheat Engine is an open source tool designed to help you with modifying single player games running under window so you can make them harder or easier depending on your preference(e.g: Find that 100hp is too easy, try playing a game with a max of 1 HP), but also contains other usefull tools to help debugging games and even normal applications.
>
> It comes with a memory scanner to quickly scan for variables used within a game and allow you to change them, but it also comes with a debugger, disassembler, assembler, speedhack, trainer maker, direct 3D manipulation tools, system inspection tools and more.

<sup><sub>Source: [About Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/aboutce.php)</sub></sup>

Cheat Engine was written with specifically Microsoft Windows libraries, so I can't cross-compile it for Mac or Linux.

**What Mac OS X or Linux alternatives are there for Cheat Engine?**

[image: [Cheat Engine 5.3 on Windows XP]]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Mac OS X

There is a Mac port for Cheat Engine available for download [from Softpedia](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Games/Cheat-Engine.shtml).

## Linux

> **Scanmem** is a simple interactive debugging utility for Linux, used to locate the address of a variable in a running process. This can be used for the analysis or modification of a hostile process on a compromised machine, for reverse engineering, or as a "pokefinder" to cheat at video games.
>
> **GameConqueror** is a GUI for scanmem, aims to provide more features than scanmem, and CheatEngine-alike user-friendly interface.

[image: [GameConqueror 0.12 on Xubuntu 12.04 LTS]]

### Ubuntu / Debian

Both `scanmem` and `gameconqueror` are available in the default Debian repositories and the Ubuntu "universe" repository.

They can be installed with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install scanmem gameconqueror
```

### Fedora

`scanmem` can be installed with the command:

```
sudo yum install scanmem
```

, but `gameconqueror` is not packaged for RPM.

### Other

The source code for `scanmem` and `gameconqueror` is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/scanmem/).

It can be compiled like other Linux source software.

Comment: Excellent research. I reached the same conclusion when researching the same problem just a few days ago. Unfortunately, CheatEngine style memory editing doesn't seem to work with games that run on Python, due to the way Python manages memory. So this will mostly work for games written in C/C++, and even then it's possible to write the game to fool programs like these.